# How to draw a edge around a patch cluster?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to draw a 30m edge around forests (see figure below). Here is my code (1 patch = 10m)

```
to create-forest-edges
let forest-edge 30
set patch-side 10

ask patches with [pcolor != 53] [
ask neighbors with [pcolor = 53] [
set pcolor green ] ] 

repeat (forest-edge / patch-side) - 1 [ 
ask patches with [pcolor = green] [
ask neighbors with [pcolor = 53] [
set pcolor green ] ] ] 
end
```

Some patches that are situated at the extremities of the world have not a green edge. I don't know why ?
Thank you very much for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about this instead:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = 53] [
  ask patches in-radius 3 with [pcolor != 53] [
    set pcolor green
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The forest must be at least 3 patches away from the edge for this to work. So, in your forest generation code, just make sure no patches near the edge are colored as forest.